# Discord Bot Python How do I Concatenate Emojis

Tags: python, concatenation, discord

```
@bot.command()
async def bar(ctx,number:int):
    text=""
    emoji = get(bot.emojis, name='emojiname')
    for i in range(number):
        text=text+"<:"+str(emoji.name)+":"+str(emoji.id)+">"
    await ctx.send(text)
```

This is returning :emojiname::emojiname::emojiname:... :emojiname: the amount you specified but doesn't return several emojis, so i wish to know if there is any way to concatenate emojis on discord python.

Comment: Your code works for me. Keep in mind that custom emojis can only be used on their originating server, unless you have Discord Nitro (which I do not know if that can be granted for bots).

Comment: indeed i solved the issue, the emojis used were animated  which for some reasons couldn't be used by the bot despite having nitro by default.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR

To Concatenate discord Emoji objects, you may use:

```py
# emoji1: discord.Emoji 
# emoji2: discord.Emoji
two_emoji_msg = str(emoji1) + str(emoji2)
```

---

In Your case the code becomes:

```py
@bot.command()
async def bar(ctx, number: int):
    text = ""
    emoji = get(bot.emojis, name='emojiname')
    for i in range(number):
        text += str(emoji)
    await ctx.send(text)
```

Though I recommend using `text = str(emoji) * number` in this case.

### Explanation

`discord.Emoji` does not have a `__add__` method. This means that you can not concatenate `discord.Emoji` instances directly (i.e `emoji1 + emoji2` is not possible), but it does have a `__str__` method which returns the valid discord emoji string representation & this string is then concatenated. Also you format the name and id like `"<:{emoji.name}:{emoji.id}>"` which does not work for animated emoji's, as their representation starts with `<a:` not `<:` (i.e `"<a:{emoji.name}:{emoji.id}>"`)

---

P.S *I did not completely understand your question so correct me, if this not what you meant.*

Comment: yes indeed that is what i meant, how do i close a topic ?

Comment: You can accept this answer as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)